# Zero is not showing as prefix in excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a table contains below data.

```
emp_name emp_id
Test1    0011
Test2    0532
```

i am downloading the data in a excell using php. below is the code.

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "usr"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "pass";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "db_name";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "table_name"; //MySQL Table Name 
$timezone  = +6;
$date_time=gmdate("Y_m_d-H-i-s", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I"))); 
$filename = "ALL_Report_$date_time";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "SELECT name,emp_id from emp_info";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or 
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select 
database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . 
mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
 }
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}   

?>
```

Using this script i am getting the data properly but when i am opening it's in excell. the prefix 0 is not showing in excell sheet.

Data is showing in below format.

```
emp_name emp_id
 Test1    11
 Test2    532
```

Please help how i can get the data with prefix 0 zero.

Comment: Some techniques to consider outlined here: [Keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7)

Answer (score 0):

excel has an issue with displaying leading 0's here a trick in excel

Select the cell or range in question.
Right-click the selected cell or range and choose Format Cells from the context menu.
Click the Number tab.
Choose Custom from the Category list.
In the Type field, enter the number of 0s necessary to accommodate the largest value. For instance, if the largest value contains four digits, enter four 0s.